# Use of got in "I got this"

Tags: grammar

When I am doing difficult task and my friend says"are you sure you can do this?"
Then I reply "I got this"
By grammar,I think it is simple past tense but i talking about present.A t.v character used this in direct speech in an episode in similar condition.i don't understand this use of "got"

Answer (score 1):

"I have got" or "I got" can informally mean "I have" (present tense). "I got this", in extremely conversational and slangy US dialect, can mean "I can do this task and have control", when said to a colleague or collaborator.

> **I/I've got this**
>   mainly US informal
>
> used to tell someone that you can
>   or will deal with something:
>
> It's OK, I got this. Go back to what you were doing.

[I got this/I've got this (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-i-ve-got-this)